# Extract link from ORG header and insert as property?

Tags: org-mode, hugo

supposing I have following ORG header

```
* [[http://...][Description]]
```

How do I extract the link and insert it as a property? My desired outcome should look like:

```
* Description
  :PROPERTIES:
  :URL: http://...
  :END:
```

Till now I only found how to remove the link from the header:

```lisp
    (defun afs/org-replace-link-by-link-description ()
        "Replace an org link by its description or if empty its address"
      (interactive)
      (if (org-in-regexp org-link-bracket-re 1)
          (save-excursion
            (let ((remove (list (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))
                  (description
                   (if (match-end 2)
                       (org-match-string-no-properties 2)
                     (org-match-string-no-properties 1))))
              (apply 'delete-region remove)
              (insert description)))))
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the URL from the match in some variable (say `url`) and then do `(org-entry-put  nil "URL"  url)`:

```el
(defun afs/org-replace-link-by-link-description ()
    "Replace an org link by its description or if empty its address"
  (interactive)
  (if (org-in-regexp org-link-bracket-re 1)
      (save-excursion
        (let ((remove (list (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))
              (description
               (if (match-end 2)
                   (org-match-string-no-properties 2)
                 (org-match-string-no-properties 1)))
              (url (org-match-string-no-properties 1)))
          (apply 'delete-region remove)
          (insert description)
          (org-entry-put nil "URL" url)))))
```

See the doc string of the function with `C-h f org-entry-put` and also see the [Using the Property API](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Using-the-Property-API) section of the manual, which you can get to  from inside Emacs with `C-h i g(org)Using the Property API`.

Comment: Thanks! That `org-entry-put` did the trick.

Comment: If this answered the question to your satisfaction, please [accept it](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).